# Many NSTabViewItems in a Single NSTabView

Tags: c#, xcode, cocoa, monomac

I have an application where the tabs are draw it dynamically depending of the numbers of items of a configuration file (i know, is not the best idea, but is a requeriment of a client). The problem is that the tab can't fit in the NSTabView, they are truncated.  I dont know if there are an option for many tabs like in Windows in the NSTabView?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. I know you tagged it c#, but here is a Objective-c way of doing it..

I imagine a NSArray holding the tabs and then add and remove the array objects as tabs as you click the arrows.

Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Look at:

```
– addTabViewItem:
– insertTabViewItem:atIndex:
– removeTabViewItem:
```